# MigrateSQLMap with multiple same-name source keys?

Tags: 7, migrations

I'm using migrate module 7.x-2.5 with a MySQL source database. My records are defined by the intersection of two tables, so I need two keys in my $source_key parameter to [MigrateSQLMap()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21migrate%21plugins%21sources%21sqlmap.inc/function/MigrateSQLMap%3A%3A__construct/7). I've done this before, no problem. But in this case, the columns have the same name, both "id". Because the column name is used as the key in the $source_key  array, the second "id" would replace the first "id".

I tried defining an alias for one of the columns with addExpression() and using the alias (type_id) as one of the keys. This correctly registers multiple source keys and shows the correct record count on drush ms, but fails on drush mi with a SQL error: "Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'type_id' in 'on clause'".

In the short term, I can just create a new column in one of the tables and duplicate the "id" values, but I'd like to know if there's a way to do this entirely in migrate code without altering the source database.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a solution without altering the source database -- although there are in my opinion clean ways of altering the source DB; and it's not a ton of code:

In either your migration module hook_install() function or a pre/post Import hook call (https://drupal.org/node/1343112) simply using a custom db_query() such as:

```
db_query("CREATE TABLE foo LIKE other_table; INSERT INTO foo FROM (intersection query); ALTER TABLE foo (change id to type_id);");
```

You can drop/recreate the table as apart of a pre/post import call.

You just have to get the SQL right and it's all of 3 SQL statements, and 1 or 2 Drupal hook functions to make it all repeatable using Migrations.